PostgreSQL: get the TOP revenue-generating staff member per each store
So I'm using dvdrental DB and I want to get top revenue-generating staff members in 2017 indicating each store.
The problem is I'm getting all employees and their revenue but I need only 1 TOP staff member per store.
I'm also restricted in using window functions.
Here's my query
SELECT staff.first_name, 
        staff.last_name, 
        address.address,
        SUM (payment.amount) AS revenue_generated
FROM payment
INNER JOIN staff ON staff.staff_id = payment.staff_id 
INNER JOIN store ON store.store_id = staff.store_id 
INNER JOIN address ON address.address_id = store.address_id 
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM payment.payment_date) = 2017
GROUP BY staff.staff_id, address.address_id
ORDER BY revenue_generated DESC;

And here's the result
Hanna   Carry    28 MySQL Boulevard 79736.45
Hanna   Rainbow  47 MySakila Drive  40537.94
Peter   Lockyard 47 MySakila Drive  40077.97
Jon     Stephens 28 MySQL Boulevard 33927.04
Mike    Hillyer  47 MySakila Drive  33489.47

So I kinda want it to be like this without using LIMIT:
Hanna   Carry    28 MySQL Boulevard 79736.45
Hanna   Rainbow  47 MySakila Drive  40537.94


@Atmo That's a Microsoft SQL Server thread, and the question here is about 1 top row for each group, but the top is decided based on an aggregate function, not something in the source data.

MS Server and so what? ROW_NUMBER()/RANK()/DENSE_RANK() suggested in the answer I linked work in postgres just as well. As for the aggregate, the query in the question already does it...

That more or less works, more or less the same way in most SQL implementations. That's not reason enough to cross-link threads between different RDBMS as duplicates of one another - unless we also decide to shut down all threads asking about sqrt as duplicates of some antique language, just because that also more or less works more or less the same way in most languages and dialects. I agree it's extremely likely this thread's a duplicate, but I'm arguing that's not the best choice to link to.

You could argue this thread seems to have the unique element of OP asking "how do I apply that here". Ultimately, it's a question of who is closing this thread helpful for: OP leaves discouraged, future visitors get re-routed from a specific problem on the same dvdrental educational sample PostgreSQL db to a vaguely related T-SQL thread.

Interesting to see how you need to lie to make your point hmm? Putting more or less works, more or less the same way in italic like you did to make people believe this is a quote from me when it is not (what you were answering is the unedited automatic comment from when I tagged the question as duplicate) can only be called that: lying. Also, I'd argue the window functions are a superior solution to your answer precisely because they work the very same way (same queries will be understood and return the same results) in other databases, that is what following a standard such as SQL is for.

DISTINCT ON is a Postgres-only extension to the language. Also, your answer does nothing to address ties of 2 or more staff, which is a point addressed in the linked answer. It also won't allow to have the top N records for each group (with or without ties), all things very easily addressed by the window functions in my comment. Probably off-topic for this site but in the case of evaluating staff, that could mean discriminating employees by paying a higher bonus to only the top performer when in fact, several people could deserve the same amount.

The primary use of italic font or cursive is not quotation, it's just emphasis - if that was meant to be a quote, I'd use quotes, with or without the cursive. I'm surprised how quickly you jumped to an accusation this convoluted beyond reason, stemming not from something I said, but from your misunderstanding or a wild overinterpretation of a font. You're free to dislike distinct on and favour window functions and not only will I not argue with you, I think it's a prefectly reasonable default choice. Thing is, OP specified "I'm also restricted in using window functions.".

@Atmo If you felt attacked, challenged or manipulated through devious use of italics - that was not my aim and I apologise. I underlined my point was an RDBMS mismatch and Charlieface already addressed it by adding a PostgreSQL distinct on thread to the links prior to closing the thread. The commentary about window functions vs distinct on would be more fitting under the answer you're addressing, if you mean to continue the topic, but it doesn't seem like we disagree on any major point. OP got an answer, thread got deduplicated, you got agreement and apologies - I hope we're done here.

You can wrap that in a subquery and add a distinct on, to get one record for each store_id. If your primary key names match the foreign key names, you can use the shorter JOIN...USING().
Demo at db<>fiddle:
SELECT DISTINCT ON (store_id) 
       first_name, last_name, address, revenue_generated
FROM (
    SELECT  store_id,
            staff.first_name, 
            staff.last_name, 
            address.address,
            SUM (payment.amount) AS revenue_generated
    FROM payment
    INNER JOIN staff USING (staff_id)
    INNER JOIN store USING (store_id)
    INNER JOIN address USING (address_id)
    WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM payment.payment_date) = 2017
    GROUP BY store.store_id, staff.staff_id, address.address_id) AS subq
ORDER BY store_id, revenue_generated DESC;




first_name
last_name
address
revenue_generated




John
Doe
Park Ave 1
3000


Tamara
Yorke
Brooklyn Bvd 2
4000



Your idea with LIMIT would've worked if you used a lateral subquery, allowing each store to run their own aggregation for each of their employees in 2017, order by that in descending order, then limit 1. The limit would be applied to each store's subquery separately, resulting in them getting just one row out of it, each.
